# how to check that record updated or not using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

In this block of code I updated a record of a model
 `IPAdress.`

how can I check now that record has updated or not.

```
let IPAdress = await model.IPAdress.update(data,{ where: { id } });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if index 0 of an array is 0 then it mean that record has not updtaed yet.
let IPAdress = await model.IPAdress.update(data,{ where: { id } });
if(IPAdress[0] == 0) throw "Error Message";
else { print("record has been updated ");
```

Comment: Thank you soo much its working. i tested invalid demo data and it's throwing an error.